# Need to make a java program to convert UML diagram to java class on netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, uml

I just want to quickly make a java file (using Netbeans IDE 8.0) to convert two UML diagrams to java files which I have already written.

Note: the class doesn't actually have to work universally with all UML diagrams, but it just has to work with both of these two.

The UML diagrams are: 
CarUML.txt

```
Car
===================
- cost : int
- color : String
- make : String
+ count : int
===================
+ Car ( int cost )
===================
```

And PetUML.txt

```
Pet
===================
- species : String
+ isChipped : boolean
- name : String
- age : int
===================
+ Pet ( String name )
===================
```

I just want a file that will output the following from them:

Pet.java

```
package UMLconv;

public class Pet {
  private String species;
  private String name;
  private int age;

  public Pet (String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

}
```

and Car.java

```
package UMLconv;

public class Car {
  private int cost;
  private String color;
  private String make;
  public int count;

  public Car (int cost) {
    this.cost = cost;
  }

}
```

This is what I have at the moment:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CodeFromPseudo {



    public static void main(String[] args) {



          Scanner scan = new Scanner(
                CodeFromPseudo.class.getResourceAsStream("CarUML.txt"));      

        //Scanner scan = new Scanner(CodeFromPseudo.class.getResourceAsStream("PetUML.txt"));

        String line;

        String [] words;        

        while(scan.hasNextLine()){

            line = scan.next(); 

            System.out.printf("public class %s {\n",line); 

            scan.nextLine();
            scan.nextLine();


            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {       

            words = scan.nextLine().split("\\s+"); 

            System.out.print((words[0].contains("-")) ? "private" : "public"); 

            System.out.printf(" %s %s;\n\n", words[3],words[1]); 

            }

            scan.nextLine();



            words = scan.nextLine().split("\\s+"); 

            System.out.print((words[0].contains("-")) ? "private " : "public "); 

            System.out.printf("%s (%s %s) {\n",words[1],words[3],words[4]); 

            System.out.printf("this.%s = %s;\n",words[4],words[4]); 

            System.out.println("}\n}"); 




            scan.nextLine(); 

            }

        }


       }
```

Not sure what I'm missing now?  Thanks

Comment: For now your question looks off-topic as code writing request, which we don't do on Stack Overflow. But we can assist you with solving problems in your code. You just need to [edit] your question and include your code attempts and describe what seems to be problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is code writing request.

Comment: sorry didn't realise that, can I edit it to add my attempts so it's not a writing request?

Comment: Yes, use [[edit]] option (placed below your post).

Comment: You might also add why isChipped got lost and why you don't need getters for the private fields.

Comment: edited to show where my code is at currently, any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you are attempting to write a code generator.
I am chief architect at BITPlan - a company offering a tool for creating generator generators see http://www.smartgenerator.org

There are tools available for this task but you can also do it from scratch.
Your start is o.k. you are reading in your input and trying to directly output what you got. Instead of doing this one step approach you might want to split your code into multiple parts:

1. scanning the input and reading the relevant parts class and attribute names into a corresponding java class structure jclass/jattributes/joperations
2. doing any modifications necessary (in your case this step might be unnecessary since all your class and attribute names seem to be valid)
3. creating java code from the structure

You'll probably not get very far with this approach given your limited input - you currently only have visibility name and type of the attributes but e.g. no documentation. As an exercise it might be o.k.

Here is some sketchy code to give you a hint how to proceed:

```java
/**
 * i represent a Java class with its attribute
 */
public class JClass {
   public String name;
   public String documentation;
   // class JAttribute needs to be defined with
   // visibility, name, type and documentation fields 
   public List<JAttribute> attributes();
   // do the same approache with operations
   public List<JOperation> operations();

   public String asJavaCode {
      String code="";
      code+="/** 
      code+=" * "+documentation;
      code+=" */";
      code+="public class "+name+" {\n";
      code+="//members";
      for (JAttribute attribute:attributes) {
        code+="// "+atttribute.documentation;
        code+=attribute.visibility+" "+attribute.type+" "+attribute.name+";"
        // add generation of getters and setters here as you see fit
      }
      // add operation handling here
      code+="}";
   }
  // add code for adding attributes 
}
```